# Properly adding sAMAccountName to AD LDS schema when using userProxyFull

Tags: ad-lds

An application to work needs `sAMAccountName` attribute populated. But I also want to have this LDS instance to be a synced subset of the AD DS catalog. The synchronization works unless I try to sync this attribute too. I have figured out that `userProxyFull` has this attribute missing from `user` (among others of course).

I have manually modified the schema `userProxyFull` with the schema editor and added this attribute as an optional one. I have also restarted the LDS instance. The synchronization completes, there is no error in the log, and I have such entries that should mean the attribute is synchronized:

> Processing Entry: Page 1, Frame 1, Entry 69, Count 1, USN 0 Processing
> source entry <guid=a6c70d306402384fb002bdb96b227fff> Processing
> in-scope entry a6c70d306402384fb002bdb96b227fff.
> (sourceobjectguid=\a6\c7\0d\30\64\02\38\4f\b0\02\bd\b9\6b\22\7f\ff)
> exists in target. Converting object creation to object modification.
> Renaming target object CN=Operator 1,OU=SCADA,DC=zenon,DC=local to
> CN=Operator 1,<GUID=6ac9bd3146955e43bade7381afa2c37a>. Modifying
> attributes: displayName, **sAMAccountName**, userPrincipalName,
> lastagedchange,  Previous entry took 0 seconds (0, 0) to process

However, I can't find the `sAMAccountName` attribute with ADSI in the target user objects, only in the group objects. What am I doing wrong?

[Update]

It seems to be a tooling problem, as Sysinternal's ADExplorer lists the attribute.

The new question is: *is there a more "canonical" way to transfer the `sAMAccountName` attribute than what I have done?*

Answer (score 1):

Adding a custom attribute to an AD LDS instance is a supported method, and you have already taken the right steps by using the schema editor to add the sAMAccountName attribute as an optional one to the userProxyFull object class.

The fact that the synchronization completes without errors and you can see the sAMAccountName attribute in ADExplorer indicates that the attribute is being synchronized correctly. The attribute may not be visible when using ADSI due to caching or other factors.

If you want to transfer the sAMAccountName attribute to the AD LDS instance in a more "canonical" way, you could try using a different tool or method to perform the synchronization. For example, you could use Microsoft's Identity Integration Feature Pack (IIFP) to synchronize data between AD DS and AD LDS, or you could use the Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM) or Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Connect tools.